# Uploading Json files using FileInput Shiny App

Tags: r, json, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that will read a .json file into a table for viewing.

I have tried reading in the data and outputting it using DataTable and fromJson function from Json Lite

```
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 

library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(rjson)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Json Test"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("Json", "Choose Json File",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c(".json"))
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("data")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fill <- reactive({
    df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(input$Json)
    Branch_10 <- df$branch_items$issue_items[[1]]
    return(Branch_10)
  })

   output$data <- renderDataTable({
    fill()
   })


}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The file looks like it is being read in but no table is being formatted.  If you have experience with loading .json files into shiny it would be great if you could give me a few hints as how to solve this.

Comment: Is the code above your entire app? It looks like you are missing some key pieces like `mainPanel()`. Could you also add a link to the JSON file you are testing with, it looks like the contents/names will be important for parsing the read in values

Comment: Thanks Nate.  Actually I only posted snippets.  Main Panel, etc. are indeed in tact.  The json file is for work so I can't.  But I can read it outside the app with R using fromJson().  No problems.  Basically I was just hoping there was a standard workflow (like there is for .csv files) in shiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RJSONIO` and `rjson` works for me, using `write()` and `fromJSON()`. To upload the file into the shinyapp you can extract the filepath by `input$Json$datapath`.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(RJSONIO)
library(rjson)
library(DT)
write(toJSON(mtcars), "test.json")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("Json", "Choose Json File",
              multiple = FALSE,
              accept = c(".json")),
    DTOutput('tbl')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT({
      req(input$Json)
      as.data.frame(fromJSON(file = input$Json$datapath))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you Big.  But I'm looking for the user to have the ability to upload a .json file using Inputfile().  After the .json file is uploaded we can display it using DT.  Any ideas?  I updated my code above.

Comment: Is there something that can be added? Otherwise an upvote would be appreciated :)